# ¿Por qué cuando uso wire:model en un compomente livewire pierdo los estilos javascript?

Tags: select2, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Buenas a todos primeramente. Explico mi problema. Estoy trabajando con un componente livewire en laravel en el cual estoy usando selects anidados y funcionan perfectamente el problema esta en que quiero darle estilos a los select con un plugin llamado select2 pero al cambiar el valor del primer select se pierden los estilos del select2. Pudieran ayudarme por favor? Gracias de antemano.

Este es el código:

**Componente livewire**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Modelo del componente**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aquí pongo el script que necesito en la página principal del componente**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ahora para que puedan ver a que me refiero así es como se ve sin seleccionar nada en el primer select:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero en cuanto lo selecciono pierde los estilos:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ven esto es a lo que me refiero. Ya intenté usando en el segundo select la propiedad wire:ignore y me mantiene los estilos pero no me pasa los datos del select a la vista. Pudieran ayudarme?

Comment: Podrías poner el código por favor?. Así resultaría más fácil hacerse una idea una vez visto.

Comment: Mire a ver ahora @OscarPortillo

Comment: @luisitomorales ¿se observa algún mensaje de error en la consola?

Comment: no no se observa ningún error

Comment: mira en el css la clase que le pone al elemento una vez seleccionado, y luego mira con el inspector de elementos que clase le pone.

Comment: mientras no está seleccionado nada utiliza varios estilos, pero en cuanto seleccionas algo y revisas el inspector no salen ninguno. Según estuve leyendo cuando se usa wire:model  se generan algunos conflictos con el código que se escriba en JavaScript, pero por más que busque no encuentro como solucionarlo. Es como si cuando se realiza algún cambio en el componente recargará esa parte pero no el javascript de la pagina principal que es donde están los estilos.

Comment: Le diste solución al problema?

Answer (score 0):

Es por que se renderiza. Pon tu select dentro de un div así:

```
<div wire:ignore>
  tu select
</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.